# std::copy causes error without exception

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

I have this code to copy an integer:

```
int parseInt(const char* data, unsigned int* ind) {
    int i;

    std::copy(&data[*ind], &data[*ind+sizeof(int)], &i); // i) STD::COPY
    // memcpy(&i, &data[*ind], sizeof(int)); // ii) MEMCPY
    std::cout << "--> " << i << std::endl;
    *ind += sizeof(int);
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    return i;
}
```

On `debian`, this code **works** without problem with **i) STD::COPY**.

Then, I have compiled and run the code on **embedded Arm** (`sizeof(int)` is also 4). The code with **i)** seems also running, printing the expected within the function.

However, it causes a problem when returning from the function.

I have tried also `return 1;` instead of `i`, but the same. It does not throw an exception, does not give any clue. I could not debug because I can not add debugger because of restrictions that I have.

It just does not continue after this function, ie:

```
std::cout << "PARSING..." << std::endl;
parseInt(data, &ind);
std::cout << "PARSED!" << std::endl;
...
```

gives out this (the value 11 is correct):

```
PARSING...
--> 11
OK
```

Then the process freezes.

However, when I use **ii) MEMCPY** instead of `std::copy`, the code works. Thus, the problem seems to me arising because of `std::copy`.

Does anyone have idea what could go on here?

Do I use `std::copy` wrongly? But then why it works on debian desktop but not on arm embedded?

Comment: I'm not sure, but dereferencing the past-the-end pointer seems fishy to me. Why not `std::copy(data + *ind, data + *ind+sizeof(int), &i)` ?

Comment: @melak47 is not the same? Anyway, I have tried. But no chance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::copy(&data[*ind], &data[*ind+sizeof(int)], &i);
```

This copies `sizeof(int)` bytes to successive elements of the `int` array beginning at `&i`, needless to say this results in undefined behavior as there's no array at `&i`.

You probably meant

```
std::copy(&data[*ind], &data[*ind+sizeof(int)], reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i));
```

The reason `memcpy` works is because it explicitly copies bytes, `std::copy` is more general as like the other standard algorithms it operates on abstract iterators, it's up to you to make sure you call it correctly.

Comment: Just for curiosity, is this kind of cast violating the *strict-aliasing* rule?

Comment: @PaoloM You can always alias with `char*`.

Comment: @MertMertce: because I can understand what the `memcpy()` line of code is doing with having to take notes.  `std::copy()` doesn't buy you much if all you're doing is copying raw bytes from one location to another.  If you're copying objects maybe `std::copy()` is the way to go, but I don't see much advantage here. And it reads like a nightmare (at least this incarnation).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I can see the argument in favour of `memcpy`, for my part I stick with `copy` because it has the uniform syntax of other algorithms (i.e. start, end, destination / predicate), and the casting ugliness is a clear signal to whoever's reading that "here be dragons" (although OP's indexing is not how I'd go about things). At `-O3` there's no difference in the generated assembly for this example when using either.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for std::copy :

```
 template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>   OutputIterator  
    copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result);  

Copy range of elements Copies the elements in the range [first,last)
into the range beginning at result.
```

You are using input iterators of type const char*. And the output iterator is of type int*.
The copy function iteraters from first to last, resulting in 4 iterations. Each iteration advancing one byte each time in the input. But the output iterator is of type int*, so each iteration the output iterator advances 4 bytes. This results in your 4 input bytes being copied with a separation of 3 bytes between each of them.
Since the element which is to receive that data is the variable i, which can only hold a single int (4 bytes), this results in undefined behaviour which manifests in writing at unspecified memory locations. Most likely overwriting the direction needed by a RET instruction to return from to the corresponding CALL.
That such a thing does not happen in debian depends on the memory model of the compiler there. And you can not trust it being consistent.

A way to solve it while still using std::copy would be to use a char* iterator for output iterator:

```
char* ptrDest = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i);
std::copy(&data[*ind], &data[*ind+sizeof(int)], ptrDest); // i) STD::COPY
```

Comment: Already received answer but thanks for details and your intent to help +1.

Answer (score -2):

Your ARM CPU may not support unaligned memory accesses. `memcpy` would handle this situation for you.